# C# - Compact Framework Windows CE - GUI Thread Blocks Higher Priority Threads

Tags: c#

I am having an issue where I have a Windows CE compact framework Application written in C#, where I have the primary GUI thread set to normal priority and a communication thread set to above normal priority to get as close to pseudo real time performance. The issue I am having is within a button handler I run a loop to load config data from a file to the GUI before allowing it to be edited. This takes around 2-3 seconds to complete. While this blocking in the event handler is happening, my higher priority communication thread is being blocked. There are no locks are thread syncs in place. The communicatio thread has no dependencies on the GUI thread.

This is how I spawn my comm thread:

```
        MbWorkerThread = new Thread(MbPollingThread);
        MbWorkerThread.IsBackground = true;
        MbWorkerThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
        MbWorkerThread.Start();
```

It is an MTA application. Also, I have tried to use Thread.Sleep(1) in the GUI event handler to yield to the higher priority thread and it does not work. I also tried using signals to yield to the higher priority thread, and that does not work. The only thing that works is if I place Application.DoEvents() in the loop while loading config in the event handler. This of coarse whas just a test, as I do not want to sprinkle Application.DoEvents() throught my code to make it work since I know Application.DoEvents() is dangerous.

My understanding is that the primary GUI thread is a foreground thread, but a thread none the less. Also, I have made the communication thread a background thread just to allow it to be killed when the primary thread is exited.

I have tried everything, I have search the Internet endlessly before asking this question.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S. - I though about a form timer but I know it runs in the GUI thread so that would not help. I though about another thread but I really did not what to marshall GUI updates via Invoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeginInvoke instead of Invoke fixed the issue. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2):

Your program starts in `Main()`, where you typically call `Application.Run( new MyForm() )`.  `Application.Run()` implements the standard Windows Message Pump, which deals with messages from the OS and other applications, including user input, inter-process communication, repaint requests, etc.

GUI events, like Button click, are dispatched via this thread.  If you perform long-running work in an event handler, other messages are not being processed.

`Application.DoEvents()` blocks the calling thread, and waits for all pending messages to be processed.  If `DoEvents` helps your communication thread when `Sleep(1)` did not, then I suspect there is a dependency between your communication thread and the GUI/Message Pump thread.

Even if this is not the case, it is not a good idea to block the GUI thread.  Move your file loading into the background with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` and marshal the results back to the UI at the end with `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: You suggestion is what I am leaning towards, so thank you. I just do not understand how a supposedly higher priority thread can be blocked by the primary thread that has a lower priority. I cannot think of anything I am doing in comm thread that would be dependent on the GUI thread. Your saying there is an implicit dependency that I do not know about? I was assuming the message pump dispatch was blocking every other thread in my process. I am starting to think it is a windows ce limitation. Not sure and again thanks for the response.

Comment: What is the comm thread doing... network, serial, using a COM component or other library?  Instead of loading a file in your Button handler, try Sleep( 5000 ) and check if your comm thread makes any progress during that time.

Comment: I am talking over a serial port to a modbus network. I have tried to sleep for anywhere from 1 ms to 1000ms, I have not tried 5000ms, but I would have expected some activivity from the comm thread. I do not know the underlying components use in the OS for the serial port but I would assume it is file access like you would do in C++. I will give that a try and see if I can pinpoint something that could be depedent on the UI thread. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I think I have figured out I do have a dependency on the UI thread. After more research and understanding, I have a feeling that the fact that I am calling Control.Invoke to different Forms, which were all created on the GUI thread, is causing the blocking of the calling comm thread. Since the GUI thread is running the event handler, the comm thread reaches the invoke, which posts a message to the GUI thread and blocks until it is processed, which in turn creates the issue I am seeing. Sometimes you feel like a fool when you figure something out that should have been simple to see.

Comment: So, since the GUI thread owns the message pump, the Application.DoEvents was allowing the messages posted by Control.Invoke to be processed, hence allow the comm thread to continue on. So, tomorrow I am going to test my fix, using BeginInvoke instead of Invoke, and moving the file reads to another thread to reduce the load on the GUI thread. I am pretty sure this was the problem. I am not going to answer my own questions until I verify it works. Thanks again for the leading me in the right direction.